# PowerBI and Stream Analytics - Auto refresh doesnt work

Tags: azure, refresh, powerbi

I have used Azure Stream Analytics to Import Data from a Hub - it worked.
I created an output to Power BI, and created a live Dashboard in Power BI with the dataset from Stream Analytics - it worked as well.

Now, if I manually refresh the report (reload the page), the newest data will be displayed (I push 100 rows in a minute from Azure to Power BI). But if I view the report in the browser, and I do not manually refresh, the report doesn't refresh automatically. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Power BI to view streaming data, it doesnt currently allow you to build reports showing this streaming data which is viewed in real time. You have to use the Q&A function and ask questions such as "Average voltage for last 10 minutes in a line chart" and it will display that streaming with new data. Once you have that base chart, you can modify it as required and then pin this to your dashboard of choice.

I hope they make it so that you dont need to use Q&A and allow you to build reports on streaming data. I feel your pain!...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/#limitations-and-best-practices

Comment: Oh no, that 's true indeed! :-) I've just tested - that's cruel , in any demonstration can be seen pointing nobody on the Q&A function . Thank you very much.